# Any way to imitate passing a number by reference, and not value, to a function?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, numbers, primitive

I understand that that isn't how primitive values are passed, but what's the best way to go about it? There are listeners set to watch the object `o`, so I need n and m to always be in sync *on the object `o`*, but I also need the number property getting incremented to be variable, so that I can pass different ones depending on some factor to `addOneTo`.

```
var o = {a: [], b: [], n: 5, m: 6};
function push5To(arr){
  arr.push(5);
}
push5To(o.a);
o.a[0]; // 5
function addOneTo(num){
  num += 1;
}
addOneTo(o.n);
o.n; // 5 :(
```

Comment: Via a closure, is one way. Otherwise, box it.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but you could always return the updated value, rather than modifying it in-place.

Comment: @Phrogz "box it"? Could you give an example of using a closure, please?

Answer (score 4):

That is because javascript arrays are passed by reference. `o.a` is an array. `o.n` isn't, it is a simple number.

One way to do is have the function return a value, and assign the value to `o.n`. Or:

```
function addOneTo(map,key){
  map[key] += 1;
}

addOneTo(o,'n');
```

Also, when @Phrogz says "box it", he means, wrap it inside a object. Objects are passed by reference. Like:

```
var o = {a: [], b: [], n: {"value":5}, m: 6};

function addOneTo(key){
   key.value += 1;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: In most languages, there's no "Pass by reference". There's only "pass by value". So in a way, what I said above (that javascript arrays are passed by reference) is wrong. What differs is *what exactly is passed by value*. For primitives, the value passed is the actual value of the primitive. For non-primitives (arrays, objects), the value is the reference of the object.

Comment: I have one doubt, other than objects will be passed by value in javascript.?

Comment: [Helpful blog post I wrote a few days ago.](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html)